# how to drag an object in a limited area without containment

Tags: jquery, project-management, gantt-chart, jquery-draggable

I have a project management system

there are some div that are gantt charts and they're Resizable and Draggable, How can I make a border or area from left and top **(for limitation)** on ***Jquery UI draggable*** for **that red** dives?

**this is the picture of my gantt cart** :
[image: gantt chart]

> the red dives (job) must not go left and top more that their parent (project).  **I can't do it with containment**

*(that two red dives are **job**, and their parent div (the green div) is a **project**)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment), it says that one of the possible values for the `containment` property is an array defining the bounding box. So no container necessary.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/dezatasu/1) *(Note that the "guide" div is only there to show where the box is, it does **not** contain the bounded draggable)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Containment Example</title>
  <style>
    div {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    div.guide {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px dotted black;
      left: 10px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 190px;
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="guide"></div>
  <div class="unbounded">I can go anywhere</div>
  <div class="bounded">I can only move around in the box
    <br>[10, 0] to [200, 200]</div>
  <script>
    $(".unbounded").draggable();
    $(".bounded").draggable({
      containment: [10, 0, 200, 200]
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```